# Making additional Oauth calls to Linkedin API after authentication through SecureSocial

Tags: java, oauth, playframework, playframework-2.0, linkedin-api

We're using the SecureSocial module to authenticate users with the LinkedIn API https://github.com/jaliss/securesocial. This works well, and the user is authorized. However, we want to populate the user profile with information from LinkedIn afterwars, and I don't know how to properly make that API call.

We have the access token (containing the oauth_token and oauth_secret), but I'm not sure how to use these fields in the next call. According to the LinkedIn API docs, I need the following fields to make another successful call to the API: oauth_consumer_key, oauth_token, oauth_signature_method, oauth_signature, oauth_timestamp and oauth_nonce. I don't know how to get access to, or generate, these values. I tried using this URL: "http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~?&" to no avail.

We're using Play! Framework 2.0.2 and Java.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you already looked at the SecureSocial source code (https://github.com/jaliss/securesocial/blob/master/module-code/app/securesocial/core/providers/LinkedInProvider.scala) ? Even if it is Scala, I think it is possible to write a Java class based on it.

Comment: That was great advice, thank you! I've got it working using a Java-fied version of what they do in the source code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you already looked at the [SecureSocial source code](https://github.com/jaliss/securesocial/blob/master/module-code/app/securesocial/core/providers/LinkedInProvider.scala) for the LinkedIn provider?

Even if it is Scala, I think it is possible to write a Java class based on it.